# Shouldn't django's model get_or_create method be wrapped in a transaction?

Tags: django, django-models

I was browsing django's source and looked at [get_or_create](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/query.py?rev=3092#L208).
Shouldn't  it be wrapped with a transaction?

Thanks

Comment: Question of the decade! I wonder why the decision to not make get_or_create atomic as well.  Occasionally I see problems due to the non-atomic get_or_create.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416213/is-get-or-create-thread-safe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [this diff](http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset?reponame=&new=8315%40django%2Ftrunk%2Fdjango%2Fdb%2Fmodels%2Fquery.py&old=8267%40django%2Ftrunk%2Fdjango%2Fdb%2Fmodels%2Fquery.py) it looks like as of [Revision 8315](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/query.py?rev=8315#L313), that has been handle explicitly within the `get_or_create()` method.

#### Update

As @reshefm pointed out, this was properly solved in [rev 8670](http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset?reponame=&new=8670%40django%2Ftrunk%2Fdjango%2Fdb%2Fmodels%2Fquery.py&old=8598%40django%2Ftrunk%2Fdjango%2Fdb%2Fmodels%2Fquery.py) where `force_insert=True` was added to `obj.save()` to ensure that during a race condition, all instances will attempt an insert (and not fall back to update) so only one will succeed while others will fail. Failing instances will proceed to do another `get()`.

In terms of release version, this fix was first introduce in release 1.0.

Comment: Look again at the code of the same revision you posted.  The get happens first(without transaction) and then a record is saved using a savepoint, but that still means you get a race condition because the get and create are not atomic together

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but the code looks fine. Assuming two requests attempt a get and fails, both will proceed to do a create. Assuming `.save()` is atomic, one of them will succeed while the other fails. The failing one then continues to do a get to retrieve the recently added data.

Comment: Indeed I looked at the wrong revision. The line here: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/query.py#L385 solves it. It forces an insert.

Comment: @reshefm good point about `force_insert`. Will update answer for future reference.