# Duplicate request threads create duplicate database entries in Django model

Tags: django, transactions, thread-safety, django-signals, django-database

**The problem**: a signal receiver checks to see if a model entry exists for certain conditions, and if not, it creates a new entry. In some rare circumstances, the entry is being duplicated.

Within the receiver function:

```
try:
    my_instance = MyModel.objects.get(field1=value1, field2=sender)
except:
    my_instance = MyModel(field1=value1, field2=sender)
    my_instance.save()
```

It's an obvious candidate for `get_or_create`, but aside from cleaning up that code, would using `get_or_create` help prevent this problem?

The signal is sent after a user action, but I don't believe that the originating request is being duplicated because that would have trigged other actions.

The duplication has occurred a few times in thousands of instances. Is this necessarily caused by multiple requests or is there some way a duplicate thread could be created? And is there a way - perhaps with granular transaction management - to prevent the duplication?

Using Django 1.1, Python 2.4, PostgreSQL 8.1, and mod_wsgi on Apache2.

Comment: Deleting my answer since I'm not addressing thread safety. Just pointing out that with your setup, if `MyModel` ever gets a duplicate created via any means, it will continually produce duplicates when `get` returns a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception.

Answer (score 2):

to prevent signals duplication add a "dispatch_uid" parameter to the signal attachment code as [described in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals).

make sure that you have a transaction opened - otherwise it may happen, that between checking (objects.get()) and cration (save()) state of the table changes.

Comment: Awesome - not sure why but it's not in the Django 1.1 docs, although it's certainly in the Django 1.1 dispatch module. Going to try this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018720/shouldnt-djangos-model-get-or-create-method-be-wrapped-in-a-transaction) may help. Apparently, a transaction is properly used with `get_or_create` but I've not confirmed this. mod_wsgi is multi-process and multi-threaded (both configurable), which means that race conditions can definitely occur. What I guess is happening in your application is that two separate requests are launched that will generate the same value for `field1`, and it just so happens that they execute with just the right timing to add 'duplicate' entries.

If the combination of `MyModel(field1=value1, field2=sender)` must be unique, then define a `unique_together` constraint on your model to further aide in integrity.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. Yes, the constraint would solve the end problem and be a good idea for general data integrity, but of course would like to avoid changing the production database if it can be avoided.

Comment: @benny, understandable, but if the constraint is valid at the data level, then it should be applied. Mistakes in the data model should be corrected as soon as possible. However, the `get_or_create` should serve your purposes in the mean time with the use of a transaction.