# Is get_or_create() thread safe

Tags: django, multithreading, django-models

I have a Django model that can only be accessed using `get_or_create(session=session)`, where session is a foreign key to another Django model.

Since I am only accessing through `get_or_create()`, I would imagine that I would only ever have one instance with a key to the session. However, I have found multiple instances with keys to the same session. What is happening? Is this a race condition, or does `get_or_create()` operate atomically?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be thread safe...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018720/shouldnt-djangos-model-get-or-create-method-be-wrapped-in-a-transaction

Comment: These answers are all outdated. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22095136/2395796) for an up-to-date explanation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actualy it's not thread-safe, you can look at the code of the get_or_create method of the QuerySet object, basicaly what it does is the following :

```
try:
    return self.get(**lookup), False
except self.model.DoesNotExist:
    params = dict([(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items() if '__' not in k])
    params.update(defaults)
    obj = self.model(**params)
    sid = transaction.savepoint(using=self.db)
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
    transaction.savepoint_commit(sid, using=self.db)
    return obj, True
```

So two threads might figure-out that the instance does not exists in the DB and start creating a new one, before saving them consecutively.

Comment: I don't see how you conclude that it's not thread-safe; at least your code snippet does not fully reflect the current implementation (and as far as I know, not even previous). It's true that the implementation used to have an issue, but it has been solved before @mvid asked. You left out the additional _try_ and _get_, so if the underlying database has a unique index for the field(s) you which are used for the _get_ part, then only one Thread will _insert_, the others will _get_; and if all threads use the same (or reasonable enough) defaults, all goes well.

Comment: @classstacker as you mentioned, the latest get_or_create() method code is NOT thread safe if the underlying database has not an unique index in the field(s) used in the query. This can be an issue when the model is defined in a 3rd party library whose code you do not want to change. I just ran into that with Django Q.

Answer (score 56):

NO, get_or_create is **not atomic**.

It first asks the DB if a satisfying row exists; database returns, python checks results; if it doesn't exist, it creates it. In between the `get` and the `create` anything can happen - and a row corresponding to the `get` criteria be created by some other code.

For instance wrt to your specific issue if two pages are open by the user (or several ajax requests are performed) at the same time this might cause all `get` to fail, and for all of them to `create` a new row - with the same session.

It is thus important to **only use `get_or_create`** when the duplication issue will be caught by the database **through some `unique`/`unique_together`**, so that even though multiple threads can get to the point of save(), only one will succeed, and the others will raise an IntegrityError that you can catch and deal with.

If you use `get_or_create` with (a set of) fields that are not unique in the database you will create duplicates in your database, which is rarely what you want.

More in general: do not rely on your application to enforce uniqueness and avoid duplicates in your database! THat's the database job!
(well unless you wrap your critical functions with some OS-valid locks, but I would still suggest to use the database).

With thes warnings, used correctly `get_or_create` is an easy to read, easy to write construct that perfectly complements the database integrity checks.

Refs and citations:

- http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/905f79e350525c95/0af3a41de4f4ce06
- http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/f0b3381b2620e7db/8eae2f6087e550bb

Comment: Many _NOs_, and justified (good answer regarding the prerequisites), but hey, in the end, it means that _get_or_create_ isn't always bad, and if all criteria are met, then it just works... missed that part in your answer. ;)

Comment: @ClassStacker indeed - there were already answers and I wanted to complement them. But you're right, it's absolutely not bad, actually it's some useful syntactic sugar!

Comment: I totally understand your motivation for complementing the other posts. Interestingly, though, I was looking for a discussion of _get_or_create_ which comes to a conclusion. But I found only discussions with half-true claims and additional _look-at-that-blog-post_ links, so when I came across your A, I found it was short and true, but sadly, without a conclusion for someone who's looking for a bit of orientation. Hence the comment. ;)

Comment: @ClassStacker i understand your point - but there was an already accepted solution :) I edited mine to make it more comprehensive. Mileage might vary with the database, but not much. With respect with your precise point, I would need to know how your "session" key is generated - and also why don't you use [django db-stored sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions) !

Comment: Cool edit. -- I'm not the OP, so can't update you on the OP's motivation.

Comment: If there is no unique then one may use `.update_or_create()`.

Answer (score 8):

Threading is one problem, but `get_or_create` is broken for any serious usage in default isolation level of MySQL:

- [How do I deal with this race condition in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235318/how-do-i-deal-with-this-race-condition-in-django)
- [Why doesn't this loop display an updated object count every five seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221247/why-doesnt-this-loop-display-an-updated-object-count-every-five-seconds/2221400)
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13906
- http://www.no-ack.org/2010/07/mysql-transactions-and-django.html

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with a view that calls `get_or_create`.

I was using Gunicorn with multiple workers, so to test it I changed the number of workers to 1 and this made the problem disappeared.

The simplest solution I found was to lock the table for access. I used this decorator to do the lock per view (for PostgreSQL):

http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/05/26/explicit-table-locking-with-postgresql-and-django/

EDIT: I wrapped the lock statement in that decorator in a try/except to deal with DB engines with no support for it (SQLite while unit testing in my case):

```
try:
    cursor.execute('LOCK TABLE %s IN %s MODE' % (model._meta.db_table, lock))
except DatabaseError: 
    pass
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. This did the trick for me. Thanks.

Comment: Locking the entire table is a huge performance bottleneck. It's incredibly heavy handed, you might as well turn the entire website off while you're serving a single request. It will work for very small applications and will not scale.