# Django: how to do get_or_create() in a threadsafe way?

Tags: python, database, django, concurrency, thread-safety

In my Django app very often I need to do something similar to `get_or_create()`. E.g.,

> User submits a tag. Need to see if
>   that tag already is in the database.
>   If not, create a new record for it. If
>   it is, just update the existing
>   record.

But looking into the doc for `get_or_create()` it looks like it's not threadsafe. Thread A checks and finds Record X does not exist. Then Thread B checks and finds that Record X does not exist. Now both Thread A and Thread B will create a new Record X.

This must be a very common situation. How do I handle it in a threadsafe way?

Comment: One of the two threads will get a duplicate record error and an exception.  There won't be duplicate data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This must be a very common situation. How do I handle it in a threadsafe way?

Yes.

The "standard" solution in SQL is to simply attempt to create the record.  If it works, that's good.  Keep going.

If an attempt to create a record gets a "duplicate" exception from the RDBMS, then do a SELECT and keep going.

Django, however, has an ORM layer, with it's own cache.  So the logic is inverted to make the common case work directly and quickly and the uncommon case (the duplicate) raise a rare exception.

Comment: I've experienced duplicate entries in a postgres database that should have been unique when I was using `get_or_create` in a view method that was getting concurrent requests, I think this is a valid concern.

Comment: @A Lee: With unique index constraints correctly defined, a duplicate should not be possible.  How were you able to circumvent the unique index constraint?

Comment: Ah, that would've fixed the issue now that I think about it more clearly.  The `get_or_create` used multiple fields and I moved it to a different execution path instead of leaving it in the view and adding a unique constraint across the multiple model fields.

Comment: @A Lee: You can still fix it.

Comment: @S.Lott: so when get_or_create attempts to create a record gets a "duplicate" exception, does it automatically try to "get" the record instead? Or do I have to do that in my code? What type of exception would Django throw in that case? I don't see any "duplicate" exception in django.core.exceptions.py

Comment: @Continuation: The underlying database raises an exception which is passed through the Django ORM.  Try it from the command-line to see what happens.

Answer (score 51):

Since 2013 or so, get_or_create is atomic, so it handles concurrency nicely:

> This method is atomic assuming correct usage, correct database
>   configuration, and correct behavior of the underlying database.
>   However, if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level for the
>   kwargs used in a get_or_create call (see unique or unique_together),
>   this method is prone to a race-condition which can result in multiple
>   rows with the same parameters being inserted simultaneously.
>
> If you are using MySQL, be sure to use the READ COMMITTED isolation
>   level rather than REPEATABLE READ (the default), otherwise you may see
>   cases where get_or_create will raise an IntegrityError but the object
>   won’t appear in a subsequent get() call.

From: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Here's an example of how you could do it:

Define a model with either unique=True:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

MyModel.objects.get_or_create(slug=<user_slug_here>, defaults={"name": <user_name_here>})
```

... or by using unique_togheter:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("prefix", "slug")

MyModel.objects.get_or_create(prefix=<user_prefix_here>, slug=<user_slug_here>, defaults={"name": <user_name_here>})
```

Note how the non-unique fields are in the defaults dict, NOT among the unique fields in get_or_create. This will ensure your creates are atomic.

Here's how it's implemented in Django: https://github.com/django/django/blob/fd60e6c8878986a102f0125d9cdf61c717605cf1/django/db/models/query.py#L466 - Try creating an object, catch an eventual IntegrityError, and return the copy in that case. In other words: handle atomicity in the database.

Comment: Thanks to whoever voted for this answer, I've added some examples to make it even easier to understand.

Comment: Yeah, a lot things changed from 2011 when the question raised. So this answer is more actual than the first one.

Answer (score 3):

try transaction.commit_on_success decorator for callable where you are trying get_or_create(**kwargs)

"Use the commit_on_success decorator to use a single transaction for all the work done in a function.If the function returns successfully, then Django will commit all work done within the function at that point. If the function raises an exception, though, Django will roll back the transaction."

apart from it, in concurrent calls to get_or_create, both the threads try to get the object with argument passed to it (except for "defaults" arg which is a dict used during create call in case get() fails to retrieve any object). in case of failure both the threads try to create the object resulting in multiple duplicate objects unless some unique/unique together is implemented at database level with field(s) used in get()'s call.

it is similar to this post
[How do I deal with this race condition in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235318/how-do-i-deal-with-this-race-condition-in-django)

Comment: This isn't actually needed, see my the other answers for better ways to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

So many years have passed, but nobody has written about `threading.Lock`. If you don't have the opportunity to make migrations for `unique together`, for legacy reasons, you can use locks or `threading.Semaphore` objects. Here is the pseudocode:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from threading import Lock

_lock = Lock()


def get_staff(data: dict):
    _lock.acquire()
    try:
        staff, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(**data)
        return staff
    finally:
        _lock.release()


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as pool:
    pool.map(get_staff, get_list_of_some_data())
```

Comment: What if, I've done `MyModel.objects.get_or_create(**data)` in other places. How can you avoid race condition in that scenario?

Comment: I think we need to avoid doing `MyModel.objects.get_or_create(**data)` in other places, and always use this function for the purpose. Am I correct?

Comment: You can override get_or_create with thread lock in QuerySet Manager, like here:

https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/13105/django-1.1.1-thread-safe.patch

However, this problem appears only in high concurrent places like pools, if your are using pool with locks in background task for e.g. and native django view, there's very small chances for race condition. But, if you get this, you should think about global locks, such as redis locks, cache values, etc.

Comment: Avoiding using it also helps, but if you really need get_or_create, think about above example.

Be careful, you can lock your worker by global lock in a view, so it can slow down your web app.