# Avoid unique constraint violations when concurrently inserting data

Tags: python, sql, django, database, postgresql

I'm implementing an importer that's using a pool of workers (powered by Celery and RabbitMQ). The data that's being imported includes user data, identified by a unique user ID, and is stored to a PostgreSQL database.

Usually I receive a lot of import files, and those files are processed concurrently. In multiple files, there can be data for the same user ID. This results in the situation where 2 imports try to process data for the same user ID *concurrently*.

If data for the specific user ID already exists, there's no issue: The database row is locked by utilizing `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. However if there's no data associated with the ID, both imports can run into the troublesome situation where both try to `INSERT` — using the same user ID.

As the user ID field has a `UNIQUE` constraint, the transactions fail.

How can I prevent this from happening? Are there other options than locking the full table?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql

Comment: @xQbert Not really, my issue is that two concurrent transactions try to `INSERT` both *at the same time*, where one will of course always fail. This happens because I don't know of any reliable way of locking this operation, like: *Lock any future `INSERT` operations that try to insert with user ID = 1234*.

Comment: But an upsert as @xQbert has suggested really does work here.

Comment: Right, I got the other question wrong, sorry. Too bad Django doesn't support that. Thanks!

Comment: Use `update_or_create()` (or `get_or_create()`). If you have a uniqueness constraint on the user ID this will be atomic. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22095136/2395796) for a good description.